# Why am I receiving an AssertionFailedError when using matches() in assertTrue()?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, regex-group, assertion

```
@Test
void hasCurrentProgress()
{
    YTVideo yt = new YTVideo();
    yt.setUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6Z8FkjGEb4&t=2s");
    assertTrue(yt.getUrl().matches("(t=)"));
}
```

I am trying to detect if there is a "t=" anywhere in the url but the test case returns false even if the given url does contain a "t=" and works in the "Check RegExp" feature on IntelliJ. Does anybody have a fix for this but still using RegEx?

Comment: `assertTrue(yt.getUrl().contains("t="));` seems simpler...

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept any characters multiple times before and after `t=`, the following should work:

```
@Test
void hasCurrentProgress()
{
    YTVideo yt = new YTVideo();
    yt.setUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6Z8FkjGEb4&t=2s");
    assertTrue(yt.getUrl().matches(".*(t=).*"));
}
```

Comment: God bless your soul thank you I have been trying to find out why this didn't work for a while.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If it works for you, you can mark the answer as accepted.